# Does iOS have something like Android's AlarmManager?

Tags: ios, swift

What is iOS' alternative to Android AlarmManager class?

So far the closest thing that I found is NSTimer. But that works only when your application is up, once it goes to the background it won't work, and I need to run some function in the background and from my business logic to decide if I want to do something or not. For example if some condition is satisfied to display local notification.

The only workaround I found is to use remote pushing notifications (silent notifications) just to wake up app, and from there you can implement your business logic.

*IMPORTANT NOTE*

From what I have found on few places is that people are complaining about using silent notifications to do this because your application might be rejected on app store.

Comment: What's the function you need to run? Is it a timer, an if statement, a location? A query?

Comment: There is [no real](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) background services for iOS apps. Please rethink your logic so that you do not need to do that in background.

Comment: The question was related to any custom function like func runMyOwnMethod(){...} every 15 min.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser, I can't rethink my logic, since this is what I need in my application.

Comment: As stated by @SmokeDispenser, iOS **does not** let you run active processes in the background like Android. You will need to find a different approach.

Comment: How can anyone on iOS implement a calendar app that pop up reminders for my meeting at 2:30 tomorrow? How can there be so much doubt raised about this question? How can you "redesign" an app whose purpose it is to wake up at an appointed time and inform the user of something they want to be reminded of?

Comment: Calendar app uses Local Notifications to remind users for their meetings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**There is none**.

As already stated in the comments, [the documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) is quite clear on that:

> Always try to avoid doing any background work unless doing so improves the overall user experience. An app might move to the background because the user launched a different app or because the user locked the device and is not using it right now. In both situations, the user is signaling that your app does not need to be doing any meaningful work right now.

with the following exceptions:

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that record audio content while in the background
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Comment: So how about this part: "...unless doing so improves the overall user experience." so in case when you have some automated process that can help user to do something on behalf of the user, and notify the user when he really needs to be notified they prevented that, but you can still implement pushing notifications (e.g. Skype messaging or whatever).

Ok, so if there's no appropriate way to translate AlarmManager to iOS, what would be alternative workaround to achieve as much as possible similar behaviour?

Comment: I think with my edit, there is not much more to say. There is no way to run long running tasks reliably in the background. Even push notifications (doing the timing on a server and sending push events) are not reliably delivered to a device in a timely manner.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact equivalent. Please read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

The relevant part:

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that record audio content while in the background
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> Apps that implement these services must declare the services they support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of those services. Declaring the services lets the system know which services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your application from being suspended.

If the function you are trying to call does one of the above, the documentation explains how to use background tasks or other methods to accomplish that.