# How to trigger an alarm after a certain event in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alarm, mobile-development

I'm developing an app in flutter and, after a certain event occurs in the background, I need to trigger an alarm that alert the user. I was only able to trigger a pop-up notification but not an alarm. How can I do?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the android part you can use the package "android_alarm_manager": https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

I've also checked if there is something equivalent for iOS, but unfortunately it seems like there isn't because of the following reasons answered in this post:
[iOS alternative for Android AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943191/ios-alternative-for-android-alarmmanager)

I'm new to stackoverflow but hope this could help.